# Seperating array values in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have kind of complex array on which is dynamically populating array depending on number of type child and adults name written on form and have to send data in single array but have to seperate childs and adults not like one adult then child now it's being like that.

Here us my code

```
$h = array (
'code' => $_SESSION['post_data']['canc_code'],
'first_name' => $_SESSION['post_data']['bofullname'],
'last_name' => $_SESSION['post_data']['bolastname'],
'email' => $_SESSION['post_data']['boemail'],
'special_request' => $_SESSION['post_data']['special_req'],
'phone_country' => $_SESSION['post_data']['bocountrycode'],
'phone_no' => $_SESSION['post_data']['bomobnum'],
);
$outerKey = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['post_data']['adult'] as $key => $adult){

$h['room_pax_details'][$outerKey] = [
    'room_no' => $key,
];

$innerCounter = 0;
foreach($adult as $innerKey => $innerValue){
    if(isset($adult['first_name'][$innerCounter])){
        $h['room_pax_details'][$outerKey]['pax'][] = [
            'firstname' => $adult['first_name'][$innerCounter],
            'lastname' => $adult['last_name'][$innerCounter],
            'type' => $adult['type'][$innerCounter],
        ];

        if(isset($_SESSION['post_data']['child'][$key])){

            foreach($_SESSION['post_data']['child'][$key]['first_name'] as $childKey => $child){
                $h['room_pax_details'][$outerKey]['pax'][] = [
                    'firstname' => $_SESSION['post_data']['child'][$key]['first_name'][$childKey],
                    'lastname' => $_SESSION['post_data']['child'][$key]['last_name'][$childKey],
                    'type' => $_SESSION['post_data']['child'][$key]['type'][$childKey],
                    'age' => $_SESSION['post_data']['child'][$key]['age'][$childKey],

                ];

            }
            //unset($_SESSION['post_data']['child'][$key]);
        }




        $innerCounter++;
    }

}
$outerKey++;
}



 $fn = json_encode($h);
```

Expected sample json,

```
{

                "first_name" : "James",
                "last_name" : "Meitner",
                "email" : "test@gmail.com",
                "special_request" : "",
                "phone_country":"+93",
                "phone_no":"123123",
                "room_pax_details" : [
                    {
                        "room_no" : "1",
                        "pax" : [
                            {
                                "firstname" : "James",
                                "lastname" : "Meitner",
                                "type" : "Adult"
                            },
                            {
                                "firstname" : "James2",
                                "lastname" : "Meitner2",
                                "type" : "Adult"
                            },
                            {
                                "firstname" : "Richard",
                                "lastname" : "Bohr",
                                "type" : "Child",
                                "age"  : 5
                            },
                            {
                                "firstname" : "Richard",
                                "lastname" : "Bohr",
                                "type" : "Child",
                                "age"  : 5
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "room_no" : "2",
                        "pax" : [
                            {
                                "firstname" : "James",
                                "lastname" : "Meitner",
                                "type" : "Adult"
                            },
                            {
                                "firstname" : "Richard",
                                "lastname" : "Bohr",
                                "type" : "Child",
                                "age"  : 5
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Here is HTML which dynamically generated as per number of rooms and adults or childs.

```
<form class="last" method="POST" action="http://happeniz.wwwmi3-sr14.supercp.com/zoalnawp/notification/">
                        <input type="hidden" name="canc_code" value="3073364c685678b3630bda25416bb42ced39fb1b4cfb6fe45f336539740cd2e4b2bb0fce8ab848012e8bff8361956c9cb492d967660339bebaa79fc32495bc67fa39e09171eb21709b535a1f3e776fbd292bfcd601c48a77f8b55c759d555ed1c7a8fb3240f4c52be67df349b81c95104376aa4055b75dd98ffe0bd14fb9ce036bc4fe8375070fcd0410447f742c876e172aa93c998ac07aab46cd23564d5dc227f5b3229b1cb6253f1184853f8feb5a10712ace86aac8f14abd4c5032d258f5e19a7d246cf7f5d77fba3e053e2be524ce6a3ac7bef6eafb4b6b2efbc095d8a1e21ac52f95234d9d8e9ac471608693c9">
                        <div class="form-group row g-mb-25">
                            <div class="col-md-6 g-mt-20">
                                <label for="">Full Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control form-control-md" name="bofullname" type="text" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 g-mt-20">
                                <label for="">Last Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control form-control-md" name="bolastname" type="text" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 g-mt-20">
                                <label for="">Email</label>
                                <input class="form-control form-control-md" name="boemail" type="email" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 g-mt-20">
                                <label for="">Country Code</label>
                                <input id="country-code" class="form-control form-control-md" name="bocountrycode" type="text" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                <label for="">Mobile Number</label>
                                <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="bomobnum" type="text" required="required">
                            </div>


                                <hr class="g-mt-10 g-mb-20">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 romms_namehead">
                                  <p class="roomss"><strong>Room no 1 :</strong></p>
                                  <p class="rooms_detail">Please fill the adults info :</p>
                                </div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 dynamic_rooms">


                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                <label for="">First Name</label>
                                <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[1][first_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                    <label for="">Last Name</label>
                                    <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[1][last_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                    <label for="">Type</label>
                                    <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[1][type][]" type="text" readonly="" value="Adult">
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                <label for="">First Name</label>
                                <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[1][first_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                    <label for="">Last Name</label>
                                    <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[1][last_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                    <label for="">Type</label>
                                    <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[1][type][]" type="text" readonly="" value="Adult">
                                </div>

                                                                                                                        <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                                    <label for="">Child First Name</label>
                                                    <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="child[1][first_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                                        <label for="">Child Last Name</label>
                                                        <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="child[1][last_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                                        <label for="">Type</label>
                                                        <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="child[1][type][]" type="text" readonly="" value="Child">
                                                        <input name="child[1][age][]" type="hidden" value="7">
                                                    </div>
                                                                                                    <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                                    <label for="">Child First Name</label>
                                                    <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="child[1][first_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                                        <label for="">Child Last Name</label>
                                                        <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="child[1][last_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                                        <label for="">Type</label>
                                                        <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="child[1][type][]" type="text" readonly="" value="Child">
                                                        <input name="child[1][age][]" type="hidden" value="7">
                                                    </div>
                                                                                    </div>

                                <hr class="g-mt-10 g-mb-20">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 romms_namehead">
                                  <p class="roomss"><strong>Room no 2 :</strong></p>
                                  <p class="rooms_detail">Please fill the adults info :</p>
                                </div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 dynamic_rooms">


                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                <label for="">First Name</label>
                                <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[2][first_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                    <label for="">Last Name</label>
                                    <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[2][last_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                    <label for="">Type</label>
                                    <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[2][type][]" type="text" readonly="" value="Adult">
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                <label for="">First Name</label>
                                <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[2][first_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                    <label for="">Last Name</label>
                                    <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[2][last_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                    <label for="">Type</label>
                                    <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[2][type][]" type="text" readonly="" value="Adult">
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                <label for="">First Name</label>
                                <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[2][first_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                    <label for="">Last Name</label>
                                    <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[2][last_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                    <label for="">Type</label>
                                    <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="adult[2][type][]" type="text" readonly="" value="Adult">
                                </div>

                                                                                                                        <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                                    <label for="">Child First Name</label>
                                                    <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="child[2][first_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                                        <label for="">Child Last Name</label>
                                                        <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="child[2][last_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                                        <label for="">Type</label>
                                                        <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="child[2][type][]" type="text" readonly="" value="Child">
                                                        <input name="child[2][age][]" type="hidden" value="7">
                                                    </div>
                                                                                                    <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                                    <label for="">Child First Name</label>
                                                    <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="child[2][first_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                                        <label for="">Child Last Name</label>
                                                        <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="child[2][last_name][]" type="text" required="required">
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md-4 g-mt-20">
                                                        <label for="">Type</label>
                                                        <input id="mobile-number" class="form-control form-control-md" name="child[2][type][]" type="text" readonly="" value="Child">
                                                        <input name="child[2][age][]" type="hidden" value="8">
                                                    </div>
                                                                                    </div>






                        </div>
                        <hr class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="">Special Requests</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control form-control-md" name="special_req" cols="100" rows="3" placeholder="Please enter comments"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 g-mt-40">
                            <input type="hidden" name="totalrooms" value="2">
                            <input type="hidden" name="totaladults" value="Array">
                            <input type="hidden" name="totalchilds" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="totalprice" value="947">
                            <input type="hidden" name="curencyyy" value="AED">
                            <input id="" type="submit" name="submit1" value="Continue" class="btn form-control-md u-btn-orange border-20">
                            <!-- <button class="btn form-control-md u-btn-orange border-20" type="button">Continue</button> -->
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Edited: Sample data is above is with two rooms in one room if there are two adults two childs so they will be seperated as adults first then childs on that room, but i am getting in return one adult then child then adult then child in that way, Need some tweaks on code for generating array.

Comment: Without sample data and expected output it's pretty much impossible to debug this code. Please [edit] your question and add some.

Comment: sorry i just edit in few minutes

Comment: @Nick Edited code

Comment: What does the input data look like that should generate that output?

Comment: Editted question with HTML which get generated dynamically, depending on number of rooms and person types. @Nick